# Enviar y obtener array de arrays js en servlet

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets

Quiero enviar por ajax un array de arrays hacia un servlet en java, recibir esos datos y recorrerlos.

Ej:

```
var datos=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
$.ajax({
   url: servlet,
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'post',
   data: { lista: datos },
   success:function(){}
  });
```

Enviar eso por ajax a un servlet. ¿Cómo lo recibo y recorro en java?

Comment: Me parece que la información estará en el contenido del cuerpo del request, es decir que debes leer el contenido directo del `InputStream` que es el resultado de [`HttpServletRequest#getInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--), en un String, luego parsear el JSON y podrás leer el contenido de `datos` como prefieras.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste con: `request.getParameterValues('lista[]')[0]`

Comment: No funciona eso. Aparte de enviar el array de arrays también debo enviar más variables.

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando datatype `json`, por lo que jQuery enviará tus parámetros como cuerpo del la petición, no como el clásico `multipart/form-data` por lo que no los puedes recibir con `getParameters`, tienes que leer el cuerpo de la petición, y eso te devolverá un `json` como cadena, luego puedes pasarlo a algún *parseador* de json y obtener los datos de tu arreglo.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

  StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
  String line = null;
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      jb.append(line);
  } catch (Exception e) { /*Error leyendo los datos, ejm. conexión interrumpida, etc. */}

  try {
    // jb.toString(); // el json como cadena
    JSONObject objetoJson =  HTTP.toJSONObject(jb.toString());
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    // error formateando el json
    throw new IOException("Error convirtiendo el Json");
  }

  JSONArray arr = objetoJson.getJSONArray("lista"); // obteniendo tu lista
}
```